# android: same width for buttons which equals to widest button

Tags: android, button, markup

i have two buttons put in line inside layout. i d' like them to have the same width. but width of every button have to be equal the widest of them. now i use ViewTreeObserver.

```
    class LayoutListener implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener{
    private Button btn1, btn2;

    public LayoutListener(Button b1, Button b2){
        btn1 = b1; btn2 = b2;
    }
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int w1 = btn1.getWidth();
        int w2 = btn2.getWidth();
        if (w1 < w2)
            btn1.setWidth(w2);
        else
            btn2.setWidth(w1);
    }
}
```

but it's not good decision becase elements are redrawn after they was shown to the user and it looks terrible. 
and question as you can guess, how can i reach needed behavior? is there way of markup manipulating or i should implement special code? it's desirable to avoid creating custom layout that could be used as a container for buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i call `getWidth` derectly after inflatation it's always return 0. 
To prevent it before get size i should init measure process by using `measure` function.
This is my code (but i' m not sure it's the best and the fastest way)) ):

```
....
view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.send_command_item, null);
btnOff = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnOff);
btnOn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnOn);
set_w(btnOff, btnOn);
.....

public void set_w(Button btn1, Button btn2) {
    btn1.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btn2.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    int w1 = btn1.getMeasuredWidth();
    int w2 = btn2.getMeasuredWidth();
    if (w1 < w2)
        btn1.setWidth(w2);
    else
        btn2.setWidth(w1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you compare the button width's in the onCreate() method of your activity and set them then, or do you need to change their size at a different time?

EDIT:

After you inflate your view you can create two Button variables and use `(Button)yourViewName.findViewById(R.id.buttonid);` to bind them.  You can then use getWidth() and setWidth() to compare and modify them as you need.

Comment: i create view as: view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, null) and cannot catch oncreate method. And besides that, if i'm not mistaken (i 'm new in android developement), getting calculated sizes is possible only in onMesure method, is not it.

Comment: Are the buttons defined inside of an xml file?

Comment: sorry for late answer. i was needed to set aside my android project for a while. I've tried as you recommended: see my answer in this topic